# How to multiply number of rows in result set Testing pagination

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

Testing pagination in laravel 5 app with request

```
$modelsList = Model
    ::getByStatus('A')
    ->get();
```

I have difficulties as there are too few data in Model table.
If there is a way with eloquent/collection to multiply number of rows in result set 
with less code as possible and easy to return ?

Comment: So, howmany do you get and how many should you get?

Comment: In my case I got 5 rows, but I would easily have, 50, 200, 500 rows.

Comment: Howmany results are currently in your database? Howmany records do you get when you do the select statement with the same query?

Comment: 5 rows. The app is at dev stage with some default data from miogration.

Comment: So if I understand you correctly, you have 5 records in db, but you want to fill database with more(50, 200, 500) records?

Comment: If so, you may need to get known to seeders: https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/seeding